# C++ Array name from variable

Tags: c++

I would like to get some help with c++.
Im trying to change the array name using value from variable. something like this:

global variables:

```
string array1[5][5];
string array2[5][5];
```

in a function:

```
string var;
if (option1) { var = "array1"; }
if (option2) { var = "array2"; }
var[1][1]="some data";
```

unfortunately this does not work. is there any way to manage the arrays like this?

Comment: Your var is a String, how can var[1][1] work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. You should

```
string array1[5][5];
string array2[5][5];

string (*var)[5];
if (option1) { var = array1; }
if (option2) { var = array2; }
var[1][1]="some data";
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a pointer:

```
decltype(array1) *ptr{};

if ( option1 )       ptr = &array1;
else if ( option2 )  ptr = &array2;

if ( ptr )
    (*ptr)[1][1] = "some data";
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

You *could* use another level of array indexing:

```
string array[2][5][5];

int var;
if(option1) {var = 0;}
if(option2) {var = 1;}
array[var][1][1] = "some data";
```